# Xcode 4.2 iOS SDK 5 View Based Application

Tags: ios, xcode, view

does anyone know how I can start a new view based application in Xcode 4.2? There is no option to do this like there was in previous versions of Xcode. Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's now called "Single View Application".

[image]

Comment: I thought the Single template was called Navigation based application :(

Comment: They moved the order of templates around and evidently removed the nav template.